# Как будет влияет на скорость использование больших значений в ключах Dictionary или HashTable

Tags: c#, .net, оптимизация, словари

Пишу графику на C#+SFML но объектов на нужной сцене очень много, проверять каждый на необходимость в отрисовке очень затратно, поэтому собираюсь создать функцию, которая выдаёт ключ для моей коллекции в зависимости от X и Y объекта, по формуле:

Key = X * 1000 + Y;

Боюсь, что Словари теряют в скорости при использовании в нём относительно больших чисел, так ли это на самом деле?

Comment: Так возьмите и замерьте, получите результат именно для вашего кода, а не для синтетического теста.

Comment: Словарям не важны сами ключи, словарям важны 2 вещи: 1) Скорость расчета хеш функции 2) Скорость сравнения двух ключей

Comment: У меня стоит Visual Studio 2017, она сама предлагает сгенерировать метод GetHashCode (и Equals), при этом можно указать, какие поля использовать. Воспользуйтесь подобной возможностью.

Comment: Добавлю. Для словарей/хеш таблиц критически важно хорошее распределение данных по бакетам. А для этого нужна хорошая хеш-функция. Именно поэтому я предложил воспользоваться генерацией кода в Студии: она использует простые числа, что с большой долей вероятности даст хорошее распределение. У вас в коде идет умножение на `1000` - лучше заменить его на простое число.